# NameError: name 'lite' is not defined when the python function is defined in a another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to use a common file for python function and import these functions to a seperate python script.
The way I did is, I have a utilities folder and inside that a read_db.py inside read_py.py I have (please disregard the line number )

```
  1 import sqlite3 as lite
  2 
  3 def create_connection(db_file):
  4     """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
  5         specified by the db_file
  6     :param db_file: database file
  7     :return: Connection object or None
  8     """
  9     conn = None
 10     try:
 11         conn = lite.connect(db_file)
 12     except:
 13         print(f'could not connect to the database {db_file}')
 14     return conn
```

However, when I called in this funtion in my main.py

```
connect_strain = create_connection(strain_db_name)
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/research/github_projects/fludb/utilities/read_db.py in create_connection(db_file)
      8     """
----> 9     conn = None
     10     try:

NameError: name 'lite' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-5e7584b53fe2> in <module>
      1 #connecting to the DBs
----> 2 connect_pdb = create_connection(pdb_db_name)
      3 cursor_pdb  = connect_pdb.cursor()
      4 connect_strain = create_connection(strain_db_name)
      5 cursor_strain  = connect_strain.cursor()

~/research/github_projects/fludb/utilities/read_db.py in create_connection(db_file)
      8     """
      9     conn = None
---> 10     try:
     11         conn = lite.connect(db_file)
     12     except:

NameError: name 'Error' is not defined
```

What I dont understand is how lite is not defined when I did import sqlite3 as lite on top of both python files.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have `__init__.py` files in each directory?

Comment: No, do I need to add __init__.py? if so in which file should I do that?

Comment: Yes. Let's say you have `directory/module.py` and `main.py`. If you want to import `module.py` from `main.py`, then an empty file named `__init.py__` must be placed in `directory`. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure! I'll write is an answer and tick it so others will see? :)

Answer (score 0):

Python requires you to create an empty `__init.py__` in each directory in order to use it as a module.

For example, let's say you have `directory/module.py` and `main.py`. If you want to import `module.py` from `main.py`, then an empty file named `__init.py__` must be placed in directory